# How to interpret a video stream from Android in Python?

Tags: android, python, video-streaming

I want to implement a video stream from my android phone to a pc. The android stuff developed related to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352292/android-video-streaming-to-python

is done in Java. The video settings are defined by

```
  recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
  recorder.setVideoSize(320,240);
```

On the pc side I used a python script to read the outputs

```
pygame.init()
HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8888              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()

while 1:
  data = conn.recv(4096)
  print len(data)
```

I've get 1448 24 128 759 1448 1448 176 1448 1448 1448 387 32 1448 .... all the time for length of data all the time. How do I generate a "picture" from the packages?

Comment: what you are receiving over the socket is presumably an mpeg4 encoded video stream.  To generate a "picture" you'll need to decode the stream.  Try a library like pyffmpeg, http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/

Comment: Thanks for this advice ! I found a gstreamer interface for python, that should help !